# Why is a metric necessary in SR?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Simple question since I don't fully understand the purpose a metric fulfills when looking at relativistic kinematics for example.

Answer (score 1):

Very vaguely, you need a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) for any space where you wish to define distances between point/angles between vectors. It generalises the dot product in the more familiar Euclidean space. We have it in all the geometric spaces we usually deal with. In SR, the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) essentially defines the geometry we're working with and is needed to define the spacetime interval.

Comment: It might be good to say that physical symmetries suggest the definition. For relativity, the set of "tick-1" events along inertial wristwatches from a common event defines the spacetime metric.

Comment: Sure, there are many ways to address the question. I was just being as general as possible, as metric spaces are important for almost all geometric settings, not just in SR.